# How to log system function (such as mkdir) calls by php

Tags: php, mkdir

I'm a Linux server administrator (Debian) and my colleagues use php.
I like to log any use of some php functions like `mkdir` or `unlink`, so I can trace any penetration to our site for example by shell code.

Comment: Are you a control freak that does not trust your colleagues? Guess you are a fun person to work with,

Comment: If attacker wants to penetrate then `mkdir` is last thing you should worry about... To me it looks like you got no idea about PHP attack vectors and yet you are trying to protect yourself. This is not going to be much effective I am afraid

Comment: I'm so sorry, I couldn't describe my problem well, in fact I trust my colleagues. A few days ago, I found a shell code in our file server, so I removed it, I protected our codes against illegal files upload, ... and finally I decided to limit some unsecured php functions like `mkdir`, `touch`, `rename`, `chmod` and etc. The problem is that sometimes we have to use some functions like `mkdir` or `unlink`. My question is how to log any use of these function by php. In addition I thank you for your comments and I edited the main question in order to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override those functions and log whatever you want before to call them.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.override-function.php#50821

```
<?php
// Rename function to call old function later
rename_function('mkdir', 'old_mkdir'); 

// Override function mkdir
override_function('mkdir', '$pathname, $mode, $recursive, $context', 'return override_mkdir($string);');

// New mkdir function
function override_mkdir($pathname, $mode, $recursive, $context){
    do_something();

    // Call original mkdir function
    return old_mkdir($pathname, $mode, $recursive, $context);  
}
?>
```